# Xcode set an alarm with NSSpeechRecognizer

Tags: objective-c, speech-recognition, alarm

Hey is it possible to set an Alarm with NSSpeechRecognizer? If I say for example "Set Alarm at 11 o'clock" that an Alarm is set at 11:00 or with another time. I found nothing useful to make this only the thing with setting the Alarm but nothing about the recognition of numbers.
Hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to make an app or something see the apple's documentation for [NSSpeechRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechSynthesizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). And if you have already made some code that is not working, ask about it. Don't post questions without trying anything.